# unable to handle multiple checks in Nested Table of Ant Design

Tags: reactjs, antd, nested-table

check this code. when i check from one table it works properly.but when i check options from multiple tables it removes the data of other tables and only show current tables checked data,forEg :in my logic part when i select multiple checkbox from one table it uncheck all other tables

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import permissions from "../Data/PermissionAPI.json";
import modules from "../Data/ModuleAPI.json";
import { Table, Row, Col, Form, Button, Checkbox } from "antd";
const TEsting = () => {

  const [form] = Form.useForm();
const dData=[];
  const [data, setData] = useState([]); 
  const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: selectedRowKeys,
    onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
      setSelectedRowKeys(selectedRowKeys);
      console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
    },
  };

    const Permissions = ({ moduleid }) => {
    
      const perm = permissions.filter((item) => item.moduleid === moduleid);
      return (
        <Table
          style={{ width: "100%" }}
          pagination={false}
          rowSelection={rowSelection}
          rowKey={(record) => record.id}
          dataSource={perm}
          columns={columns}
        />
      );
    };

  const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log("Submit Pressed");
  };
  const columns = [
    {
      dataIndex: "key",
      key: "key",
    },
    {
      title: "Permission",
      dataIndex: "pname",
      key: "pname",
    },
    {
      title: "Description",
      dataIndex: "pdesc",
      key: "pname",
    },
  ];


  const DisplayModules = modules.map((item, index) => {
    const module = item;
    // console.log(module);
    if (module === undefined) return false;
    return (
      <Col xxl={12} xl={12} xs={24} key={index}>
        {data}
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "#ffe8c2",
            padding: 20,
            margin: "20px 20px 20px 20px",
            borderRadius: "10px",
          }}
          title={`${module.id} - ${module.modulename}`}
        >
          <div className="about-project">
            <Permissions moduleid={module.id} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(dData);
    console.log(data);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#e6e6e6" }}>
      <Form
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        form={form}
        name="editSite"
        onFinish={handleSubmit}
      >
        <Row gutter={25}>
          {DisplayModules}
          <div className="add-form-action">
            <Form.Item>
              <Button size="large" htmlType="submit" type="primary" raised>
                Save
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        </Row>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TEsting;
```

here what i want:i want checkbox Data from multiple tables in one state without empty previous state,it would be very helpful if you help in this.

Comment: how about use sandbox  demonstrating the issue?

Comment: help me here,i'm new here and i don't know how to use sandbox

Comment: i created sandbox for you, but it will be good if you place json data at moduleapi  & PermissionAPI.json -https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hugle-c3mox

Comment: Done,Please Help

Comment: can you please send me a link (it changed after you changed the json files)?

Comment: looks like i guessed the json structure https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-hugle-c3mox - is that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/ed825054d12

Comment: how to save this checkbox data into one state

Answer (score 0):

you need to decide - what data structure you want to get at the end, after user makes his choices and checks the checkboxes:

is that something like -

```
{
   "moduleId": "1",
   "permissions": [1,4],
   "moduleId": "2",
   "permissions": []
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
  const handleSelect = (record, selected) => {
    if (selected) {
      setSelectedRowKeys((ids) => [...ids, record.id]);
    } else {
      setSelectedRowKeys((ids) => {
        const index = ids.indexOf(record.id);
        return [...ids.slice(0, index), ...ids.slice(index + 1)];
      });
    }
  };

  const rowSelection = {
    selectedRowKeys: selectedRowKeys,
    onSelect: handleSelect,
  };
```